# Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' when running Flutter Template App

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I just got started with Dart/Flutter and my goal is to execute the default flutter app template generated with the `flutter --create` command in VS Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But whenever I try to run it, I get this series of errors from several files in the Material library and I can't find out what is causing them or how to solve them.

```
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/animated_icons.dart:9
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/animated_icons.dart:10
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/app.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/arc.dart:6
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
../…/material/button_bar_theme.dart:5
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
```

Running plain Dart projects like the one created with `dart create -t console-full dart_application_1 --force: running` works fine.

Can anyone tell me what causes this error?

Comment: Did you try running flutter pub get?

Comment: Where are you executing this app? Are you executing it as a Dart project? Flutter projects should be run on web browsers, emulators or real devices only, and not the console. What are your run configs? How do you run this app? (Through VS CODE directly or through the terminal?)

Comment: @Andrej Yes, i did, it didn't help.

Comment: @JustInCoding I run the app through VS Code, I tried to run it in Edge and on Windows.

Comment: For some reason I don't know, everything works perfectly fine now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

try:

1.flutter clean

2. flutter pub get

3. close your editor than open it again